# How to Convert Get Text Value to ArrayList in Robot framework

Tags: arrays, string, selenium, robotframework

I would like to know how to convert this value to ArrayList?

```
${doc1}=   Open Excel Document        filename=${OpenExcel}     doc_id=doc1
${view_bicccicmdu}=   Read Excel Row    row_num=1   max_num=6   sheet_name=UpperTT
${view_bicccicmduCheckLength}=    Get Length    ${view_bicccicmdu}
${HG}=          Get Text    ${ClickAV.CheckColumn}
${HGLenght}=         Get Line Count  ${HG}
Should Be Equal     ${HGLenght}    ${view_bicccicmduCheckLength}
Should Contain     ${HG}     ${view_bicccicmdu}        ignore_case=True
Close Excel Document
```

But the result is

```
${HG} = Nodename 
Transdate 
BICC Support FAX Detection 
Trunk Group Number 
Bill Trunk Group Number 
MGW Name Trunk 
Group Name 
Sub-Route Name 
Circuit Type 
Group Direction 
Circuit Selection Mode
```

I need to convert it to be ArrayList and should count to be 11 Records, What should I do?

Comment: You can Create a list and append the value in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the String Library and Split the string using `\n` as your separator, because in your case your data is separated by a line break, You can split the string into a list.

> Splits the string using separator as a delimiter string.
>
> If a separator is not given, any whitespace string is a separator. In
>   that case also possible consecutive whitespace as well as leading and
>   trailing whitespace is ignored.
>
> Split words are returned as a list. If the optional max_split is
>   given, at most max_split splits are done, and the returned list will
>   have maximum max_split + 1 elements

You can do the following.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test
        ${HG} =  Set Variable   Nodename\n ransdate\n ICC Support FAX Detection\n Trunk Group Number\n Bill Trunk Group Number\n MGW Name Trunk\n Group Name\n Sub-Route Name\n Circuit Type\n Group Direction\n Circuit Selection Mode\n
        @{words} =  Split String    ${HG}  \n
        ${HGLenght}=      Get length  ${words}
         log  ${words}
```

Results

```
${HGLenght} = 11
${words} = ['Nodename', 'ransdate', 'ICC Support FAX Detection', 'Trunk Group Number', 'Bill Trunk Group Number', 'MGW Name Trunk', 'Group Name', 'Sub-Route Name', 'Circuit Type', 'Group Direction', 'Circuit Selection Mode']
```

Hope This Helps

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again, @WojTek T
My final code is

```
`${HG}=          Get Text    ${ClickAV.CheckColumn}
@{words} =      Split String    ${HG}   \n
${UPPER1}=      Evaluate     "${words}".upper()
${UPPER2}=      Evaluate     "${view_dnc}".upper()
${HGLenght}=    Get Line Count       ${HG}
Should Be Equal    ${HGLenght}    ${view_dncCheckLength}
Should Contain     ${UPPER1}     ${UPPER2}`
```

I try to use "Get List Item" with Table name but It doesn't work, I should do this solution for my last question that I asking u. haha

Thank you again.